# Create multiple objects in form with shared value rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form that will take create 3 records. However in the record there is a repeated name and email address which needs to be the same for all of the records. Currently like this:

```
@competition = Competition.find(params[:competition_id])
@entries = Array.new(3) {@competition.entries.build()}
```

Entry has the following attributes:

- Name - String
- Email - String
- Title - String
- Description - Text
- Image - Uploded using Paperclip.

With this current method the user is required to enter their Name in to 3 different boxes for their different entries.

What is the rails approach in stopping the user from entering in the same data 3 times? Is it to send another object to the form and then in the create method combine them together? Although I fear this could have problems when it comes to validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery. Add these html options to the `name` field tag.

```
:class => "same-same", :onchange => "$('.same-same').each(function(name) {$(this).val(name); }, [$(this).val()]  );"
```

This would iterate over all inputs tags with class `same-same` and change the value to be same as the last changed value.

If you would like to only show the first input field then use `each_with_index` on `entries` form loop and hide the name input fields for entries with `index > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're asking here, but if you're creating multiple objects from a single form you'd probably be best off putting this logic into a "Form Object"...  See the article "7 Patterns to Refactor Fat ActiveRecord Models" from the CodeClimate blog found here (look for Section #3 on extracting Form Objects): http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models.

In short, you create a custom model including some of the necessary ActiveModel modules then create a custom save method, e.g.

```
  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

private

  def persist!
    @company = Company.create!(name: company_name)
    @user = @company.users.create!(name: name, email: email)
  end
```